# DRF "field is required" error on POST request?

Tags: django, post, django-rest-framework

```
curl --user testuser:passwordz -d '{"name":"testplatform"}' -X POST http://localhost:8080/api/v1/platforms
```

error

```
{"name":["This field is required."]}%
```

views.py

```
class platform_list(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        query = request.GET.get('name')
        if query:
            platforms = Platform.objects.filter(name=query)
        else:
            platforms = Platform.objects.all()
        serializer = PlatformSerializer(platforms, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = PlatformSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I know the auth works because if I type in wrong user or pass the error changes to "invalid credentials" . Why am I getting the field required error though?

Answer (score 6):

I forgot to add "-H "Content-Type:application/json" to the POST request.